In my project i have to create a program that reads a file and counts the number of occurrences of a specific word
So far it reads the file and counts each word in the file, but i want it to count just the word "Ball". I'm wondering how can I do that. Here's what's in the text file and the code:
Programming.txt
Ball, Ball, Cat, Dog, Ball,

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    ifstream file("Programming.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        int wordcount = 0;
        
        while(getline(file, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            string word = "Ball";
        
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                wordcount++;
            }
        }

        file.close();
        cout << "Ball occurred " << wordcount << " times";
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "File is closed!";
    }   
}

The output i get is "Ball occurred 5 times"
I tried giving each "word", "line" and "ss" variable the value "Ball":
word = "Ball"
line = "Ball"
stringstream ss = "Ball";
ss(line);"

i also tried using a for loop to count each occurrence of Ball using the word variable:
word = "Ball"
for(int i = 0; i <= word; i++)
{  
cout << i;
}

I expected both of these to count only the word "Ball"
all failed unfortunately

Coding tips: it's generally better to handle failure early. if (!file) { std::cout << "file not opened\n"; return 0; }. That way the main text isn't indented inside a pair of curly braces. And there's no need to call file.close();. The destructor will do that.

You need to compare the value of word after you read it from the file, eg:
string word;

while (ss >> word)
{
    if (word == "Ball")
        wordcount++;
}

However, this alone will not work in your case, because the words in your file are delimited by , which you are not accounting for. operator>> only cares about whitespace, so word will end up being "Ball," instead of "Ball".
Try something more like this instead to ignore the , characters:
#include <iomanip> // needed for std::ws

... 

string word;

while (getline(ss >> ws, word, ','))
{
    if (word == "Ball") 
        wordcount++;
}

Live Demo

Thank you , I literally spent hours trying to figure it out, idk why i forgot that if statements exist

Although while (getline(ss >> ws, word, ',')) works for the specific file at hand, it'll fail for most files where ball isn't always followed by a comma. For example if the file contained: Ball, Ball, Cat, Dog, Ball, Ball., the last Ball wouldn't be counted.

To count only the word "Ball" in your file, you need to modify your program to specifically check if each word read from the file matches the word "Ball" (considering case sensitivity and punctuation). You should compare each word from the stream with the string "Ball", and only increment the counter if it matches exactly.
Here is an updated version of your code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("Programming.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        int wordcount = 0;
        
        while(getline(file, line))
        {
            // Replace commas, periods, etc., with spaces to handle punctuation
            for (char& c : line)
            {
                if (ispunct(c))  // Check if the character is punctuation
                {
                    c = ' ';  // Replace punctuation with space
                }
            }
            
            stringstream ss(line);
            string word;

            while(ss >> word)
            {
                // Convert to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
                transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
                if (word == "ball")  // Case-insensitive comparison
                {
                    wordcount++;
                }
            }
        }

        file.close();
        cout << "Ball occurred " << wordcount << " times" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "File is closed!" << endl;
    }   
}


Using tolower directly as the transform() callback is Undefined Behavior for 2 reasons: 1) most standard functions (including tolower) are not addressable, and 2) if char is signed it can cause problems for tolower. The preferred approach is: transform(..., [](unsigned char ch){ return ::tolower(ch); }); Just note that transforming individual characters does not work for some foreign characters, but is OK in this example. I would opt to use a function like strcmpi() or CompareString() that can compare whole strings.
